# tryiging to use imagemagick on Azure gives "system cannot find the file" error

Tags: node.js, azure, imagemagick

I am using https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick on nodejs that runs on Azure. However, when I try to get info about a file ,ex

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
im.readMetadata('kittens.jpg', function(err, metadata){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Shot at '+metadata.exif.dateTimeOriginal);
})
```

I get the error

> "Error: Command failed: CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the
>   file specified."

It seems that the system cannot find the path to imagemagick, but how do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you'd have to install ImageMagick.

I think that whether you can do that and how you would do it depends on whether you're using Windows Azure Web Sites, Cloud Services, or Virtual Machines (and in that case, what OS you're using).

You might start by just copying the binaries into the same directory as your Node.js code to see if it will be picked up there.

Comment: Thanks @smarx. I am using web sites.The problem is that I cannot really install anything remotely and [imagemagick for windows](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows) comes only with an installer.

Comment: My guess is that you can't make this work on a shared host like Windows Azure Web Sites.